# Laravel - accessing relationship Models with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am trying to create a single page app with AngularJS as my frontend and Laravel as my backend. I've run into a problem when trying to create a table that needs to access a relationship to another Model.

For this example, let's say I have a table that displays products. Every product would also have a brand.

With Laravel's blade syntax, I would solve this by using:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Brand</th>
  </tr>
  @foreach($products as $product)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $product->brand->name }}</td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
  <!-- End of product entry for {{ $product.name }} -->
</table>
```

With Angular, I was hoping I could do this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Brand Id</th>
  </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
      <td>@{{ product.name }}</td>
      <td>@{{ product.brand.name }}</td>
    </tr>
  <!-- End of product entry for @{{ product.name }} -->
</table>
```

Unfortunately, @{{ product.brand.name }} will not work and there doesn't appear to be an easy way to access parent relationships.

FYI, my controller looks like this:

```
app.controller('CtrlProducts', function($scope, $http){

  $scope.products = [];

  $http.get('/api/products').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      angular.forEach(data, function(product){
        $scope.products.push(product);
      });
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(data);
    });
});
```

The only solution that I can think of is to make a separate api call to the Brand model and store the data into a map object. Then I could call: @{{ brandMap.get(product.brand_id) }}

Does anyone know of a simpler solution? Seems like it would be a common problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When fetching the product in your Laravel backend don't just use

```
Product::find($id);
```

but instead

```
Product::with('brand')->find($id);
```

There you go :) Corresponding docs section: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: I would, but need 15 reputation. Give me an upvote and I might be able to! ;)