# Advanced Select statement (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In the Products table i have the store_id column which connects the product with the store.

In my APIController which i use with Angular i have this return statement. I am returning a collection of products.

```
return Product::where('category_id', $category->id)
           ->select(array('id', 'name', 'newprice', 'image',
               'store_id', 'link'))
           ->paginate(20);
```

My problem is that instead of returning the store_id(from the products table) i want to return the store name, which is NOT stored in the same table. Is there any way to do that?
Is my only option the use of JOIN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you do it with Laravel(/Eloquent) relationships like this:

### ApiController:

```
$productFieldArray = ['id', 'name', 'newprice', 'image', 'store_id', 'link'];
$product = Product::where('category_id', $category->id)
                       ->select(productFieldArray)
                       ->paginate(20);

// Get the value you want (I guess it's the name attribute?)
$store = $product->store->name;
```

### Model relationships:

Product.php:

```
...

public function store() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Store');
}

...
```

Store.php:

```
...

public function products() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}

...
```

### Edit:

You have to use the with() function in your query to point out your want to receive the store data too. See: [Laravel - accessing relationship Models with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055556/laravel-accessing-relationship-models-with-angularjs) or http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading.

So you query will be:

```
Product::with('store')
    ->where('category_id', $category->id)
    ->select(productFieldArray)
    ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: the problem is that i want to output the name of the store directly to the return statement for each product. I don't use blade in my views, but angular so this approach wouldn't work for me.

Comment: can i select columns of the with('store')?  It seems to return an object of all columns in the table Stores, but i only need the name

Comment: I think you have to access it like: {{ product.store.name }} in Angular. Im not really into this, but I guess that will work here.